# When an object is equal to another object in test methods?

Tags: c#

I want to know, when an object is equal or not equal to another object with the method **Assert.AreEqual**.

I have to objects, which are tested false.
But when I test every single property with **AreEqual** the tests are successfull.

That would mean equality does not only depend on properties. Could someone explain that?

(It's a theoretical question, I cannot provide any data)

Comment: The default for equality is based on the reference for the objects. So `new object().Equals(new object())` is `false`.

Comment: Can you share what kind of objects you are comparing?

Comment: Only because two objects have the same properties doesn´t make them "equal". You have to provide some logic under whitch circumstences you consider two objects equal. There´s no automatism (except that one for reference-equality) here.

Comment: It also may depend on the unit-testing framework you use. For NUnit it's documented here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/EqualConstraint

Comment: Or in other words: only because you have two persons named "John" with same age, they are not neccessarily the same person, are they?

Comment: You could write your own custom comparison logic that uses reflection to compare all property values, and handles property recursion with whatever rules you want.